# Use of "applicationSignificantTimeChange"

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

May be I am asking a stupid question here.

I recently noticed an UIApplication delegate method

```
- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {

}
```

I was wondering what will be its actual use? Do we need to handle this. Can anyone explain a scenario that can happen in an iOS application and we need to do some coding here.

My App is really sensitive to system time, that is the reason I am asking this question. After seeing this API , I have a feeling that I am missing something here to handle.

I am just curious to know... :)

Thanks,
Ramesh Chandran A

Comment: I think [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html) pretty much cover your question: _Examples of significant time changes include the arrival of midnight, an update of the time by a carrier, and the change to daylight savings time. The delegate can implement this method to adjust any object of the app that displays time or is sensitive to time changes._

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation on iOS, this method is called:

> Examples of significant time changes include the arrival of midnight,
>   an update of the time by a carrier, and the change to daylight savings
>   time. The delegate can implement this method to adjust any object of
>   the app that displays time or is sensitive to time changes. Prior to
>   calling this method, the app also posts a 
>   UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange notification to give interested
>   objects a chance to respond to the change. If your app is currently
>   suspended, this message is queued until your app returns to the
>   foreground, at which point it is delivered. If multiple time changes
>   occur, only the most recent one is delivered.

Examples of when this should be used include:

- If your app has repeating scheduled events, such as a local notification that now is past, and your app should reschedule the next notification (like daily reminders).
- If your app displays data in time ago that needs to be correct, even if the user sets a bad time (for example a medical app that shows your current glucose reading or similar). If a glucose monitor showed an old glucose value as the users current glucose value for instance, the user could make the wrong decision and get hurt.

How you respond to this event depends on your application. You could for instance, read UTC from a server to see if the phone's UTC is correct within some margin, and take appropriate action, such as warning the user, or updating an internal offset between actual UTC and phone UTC.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

`-applicationSignificantTimeChange:` is roughly equivalent to the `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` notification.

I have a custom date picker control that highlights the today date. Subscribing to this notification allows it to change its highlight at midnight, or if the user messes with the time setting manually.